# How to use createprocess to execute adb program in PATH?

Tags: c, adb, createprocess

I have add the **adb** location into **PATH**. In my *C* project, I want to execute the flowing cmd:

```
char *broadcastStop = "adb shell am broadcast -a NotifyServiceStop";

char *forward = "adb forward tcp:12582 tcp:10086";

char *broadcastStart = "adb shell am broadcast -a NotifyServiceStart";
```

I can run the above using **system()** well. Now I want to run those hiding the console. I have found many similar question, and told **CreateProcess** can do.

Here is my code:

```
void system_hide(char *cmd)
{
    STARTUPINFOW si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    if (CreateProcessW(NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

    }
}
```

It doesn't run correctly,

I guess that the params to **CreateProcess** is wrong.

Hope for a correct version. Thanks in advance.

Comment: by the way, the **cmd** param in **system_hide** refers to *broadcastStop,...*.

Comment: Do you know what W in CreateProcessW stands for? Are you paying attention to compiler warnings?

Comment: **W** means *the Unicode version of this function*, right ? The code will compiled to **dll**, so I cannot see the runtime detailed infos.

Comment: Yes. But you are trying to pass to it an ANSI string.

Comment: thanks a lot. I changed **CreateProcessW** to **CreateProcess**, and it works.