# Use CreateProcess to execute ADB command

Tags: c++, adb, createprocess

I want to use CreateProcess() to execute an ADB command that launches an application/activity. It works using the simpler system(command) function, but I want to eliminate the creation of the command line window by system(). Below is what I have right now. I have tried using different CreateProcess()es, like CreateProcessW and CreateProcessA, but to no avail.

```
char prog[] = "C:\\Program Files\\Android\\sdk\\platform-tools\\platform-tools\\adb.exe";
char args[] = "adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.example.dmiller.myapplication/.Blankscreen";

STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

CreateProcess((LPCWSTR)prog, (LPWSTR)args, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

I got this partially from this answer [How to use createprocess to execute adb program in PATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27883824/how-to-use-createprocess-to-execute-adb-program-in-path) but when the command should be executed in my program, nothing happens (when running system(cmd.c_str()), the appropriate app is launched on the attached device). Could anyone provide some help? Alternative methods are welcome as well.

UPDATE: I have applied some things from the below post to try to provide a better question. Code has been updated to my latest version.

[CreateProcess doesn't pass command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135784/createprocess-doesnt-pass-command-line-arguments?rq=1)

Comment: _"but it isn't working for me at all."_ Elaborate this in your question please. How in particular it doesn't work for you?

Comment: _"I have updated the answer"_ You probably meant _the question_. What about checking the documentation of [`CreateProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) again. IMHO  you have at least one invalid `NULL` pointer (`lpApplicationName`) passed to it.

Comment: Yes, I meant the question.

BOOL WINAPI CreateProcess(
  _In_opt_     LPCTSTR lpApplicationName,
  _Inout_opt_  LPTSTR lpCommandLine,
  _In_opt_     LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
  _In_opt_     LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
  _In_         BOOL bInheritHandles,
  _In_         DWORD dwCreationFlags,
  _In_opt_     LPVOID lpEnvironment,
  _In_opt_     LPCTSTR lpCurrentDirectory,
  _In_         LPSTARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
  _Out_        LPPROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation
);

None of my NULL parameters are non-optional according to the documentation.

Comment: Zeroing the memory at the address of a pointer would set it to NULL, right? I think maybe you meant `STARTUPINFO si;` instead of `LPSTARTUPINFO si;`, given the way you call `ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si))`. Also, does it make sense to have a completely empty STARTUPINFO?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I tried passing in "C:\\system32\\cmd.exe" as the lpApplicationName parameter, but that does not solve the problem.

Comment: @AustinMullins, I am not sure exactly, but intuitively it doesn't make sense. I have no experience with process creation unfortunately. I did mean `STARTUPINFO si`, question has been updated.

Comment: You don't want to execute `cmd.exe` anyway. You want `adb`.

Comment: Also, you need to pass `&si` to `CreateProcess`. I assume you did that in your code because it wouldn't have compiled otherwise.

Comment: It actually does compile with just `si` being passed, but I was under the impression it wouldn't as well. You're right though. Updated again, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type-casting a `char` array to have type `LPCWSTR` doesn't make it so. The former is an array of one-byte characters. The latter is (a pointer to) an array of two-byte characters. The type cast tells the compiler that the one is really the other, and the compiler trusts you. It does not perform a conversion.

To fix this, declare `prog` and `args` to have type `WCHAR` or `wchar_t` instead of `char`, and use the `L` prefix on the literals:

```
WCHAR prog[] = L"...";
WCHAR args[] = L"...";
```

Then you can remove the `LPCWSTR` type casts because they won't be necessary anymore.

As usual, *whenever* you call an API function, it's wise to check the return value and look for any error codes. [The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) advises that you should check whether the function returns zero. If it does, call `GetLastError` to find out what the OS thinks the problem was.

Comment: My rule of thumb is "If I see code using a cast, I've found a bug".

Comment: That works, thanks! You suggestion to check the return value and look for error codes is also very helpful, I'll try to keep that in mind.