# Is there a way to execute adb commands programatically in C++? This C++ part of code is built using ndk build in android studio. There

Tags: android, c++, macos, shell, android-ndk

I referred to this link  - [Use CreateProcess to execute ADB command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637144/use-createprocess-to-execute-adb-command). The approach used in the above link requires Windows.h file which is contained in windows SDk. Since i am executing Android Studio in Mac i will not be able to get the include file. I am not sure whether the above mentioned approach can be performed using Android Studio in Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `system` or `popen` methods to start an `adb` process.

Comment: Thanks konh chun ho :) I tried to execute "su -c dumpsys meminfo package name". On executing this command the IOStream returned in null. I dont get any data.

Comment: i thought you are running `adb`? Why you are running `su`? You can get the stdout when you are using `popen`.

Comment: I need to get the Heap size, heap alloc and heap free details for the given pid or package name... so i tried to to execute "dumpsys meminfo package_name" ---- this is producing an error: "Permission Denial: can't dump meminfo from from pid=21401, uid=10061"

Comment: OK, i see what you are doing. Maybe the correct command to do is `su -c adb shell dumpsys meminfo package_name`?

Comment: already we are in adb shell right? do we need adb shell in the command? Since this process is run in the android runtime.

Comment: OK, you havn't provide enough information. So you are running this in adb shell, on a rooted phone? Then why you are mentioning Mac and Windows? The link you provided is trying to run `adb` commands ON WINDOWS.

Comment: Yes. I am running this in adb shell on a rooted emulator. Sorry for not providing enough information.

Comment: when i run this piece of code ----                                                             FILE *in;
    char buff[512];
    fflush(in);
    if(!(in = popen("dumpsys meminfo com.quixey.healthmonitor", "r"))){
        LOG_HM("command failed");
        return 1;
    }

    LOG_HM("command executed");

    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in) != NULL){
        LOG_HM("buff = %s", buff);
    }---------------- i am getting "Permission Denial: can't dump meminfo from from pid=21401, uid=10061" as the data read from the buff.

Comment: The above mentioned code is being run in an android emulator.

Comment: You still get permission denied with `su`?

Comment: Yes still getting permission denied su.

Comment: If you run adb shell on your computer with above command, you have no problem? Have you installed some SU helper app like SuperSU?

Comment: I am able to get the details after executing the command in a rooted emulator. Thanks Kong chun.